# How to ceate custom GridView for android?

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, layout

I would like to create a grid view like the one in the photo.
I tried using a GridLayout but I'd like to move the central column some pixels bottom than the left and right columns.
Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks

[image: layout for my app]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, flexbox-layout that you need is developed by GG.
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout